# How can i write a .htaccess for only 1 module in a Zend Framework project

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have a zend framework project with 2 modules - admin and default. the admin is for managing my stuff and the default should be used only for my clients. that's why i wanted to limit the default module only to the allowed domains. i searched in google and found that i can can limit the .htaccess by that code:
http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f18/get-domain-site-sent-http-request-9388/
[the green and red code].

The problem is that since everything is the zend framework works on the index.php i cant seem to be able to limit the .htaccess only for 1 module. 
so how can i do that?

thanks

Comment: Please specify what URLs you want translated, and which ones you don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading up on Zend_Acl: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1665 which will allow you to control which users can access which modules/controllers based on their assigned role